# Is it possible to remove shadows behind windows and menus?

Tags: 11.04, unity, gui, themes, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove shadows of the windows in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37654/how-can-i-remove-shadows-of-the-windows-in-unity)

Is it possible to remove shadows behind windows and menus in Ubuntu 11.04 with Unity?