# How to disable shadows for Ubuntu 15.04 for a certain window class?

Tags: unity, compiz, 15.04, conky, window-decoration

**How to disable shadows for Ubuntu 15.04 for a certain window class?**
In Ubuntu < 15.04, you could disable shadows and window decorations for a specific class of windows, using CCSM.

For a specific example:

I'd like to remove Shadow decorations from Conky windows. (Conky is a desktop monitor system.) In previous versions of Ubuntu, you could use CCSM and choose "Window decorations -> Decoration windows -> By class" and selectively remove shadows/decoration from your choice of window class.

You can see from the photo, there's shadows around the boxes on the desktop.
[image]

Attempting to enable "window decoration" plugin in CCSM now interferes with Unity's window decoration.  (Which is, naturally, a disaster. It disables Unity completely.)

[image]

How can I disable shadows for a certain window class in Ubuntu 15.04+?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI:  This solution does not work with Ubuntu 15.04:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/37654/how-can-i-remove-window-shadows-in-unity/37668#37668

Comment: You could overwrite the default theme.... are there any settings to do this under the Unity plugin itself?

Comment: Haven't used conky on a while but this is  thefirst google result I got, I remember doing something similar: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/03/solutions-to-fix-black-shadow-of-conky.html

Answer (score 2):

As the dialog suggests, there's a Unity plugin that provides decorations. You can find it in the Desktop section of `ccsm.`

In the Decorations tab, Check **Override Theme Settings** then set the shadow colors to be 0 percent opaque. No more shadows!